# Excel Formula to get Season name?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

My Task is to get Season name from Date in Excel using a formula.

So far I achieved getting Month name from Date thanks to this link:

http://dedicatedexcel.com/how-to-convert-a-date-into-a-month-name-in-excel-2010/

Is there anyway (like switch-case) in Excel formulas so I can get Season name based on month name?

Thanks.

Comment: Since they include two seasons, which season would you want to display for March, June, September and/or December?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Choose() function for that. When exactly a season starts may be open to debate. This formula assumes that the season starts at the first of the month, not the solstice and equinox days.

[image]

The formula for the Northern Hemisphere in B2 is

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH(A2),"Winter","Winter","Spring","Spring","Spring","Summer","Summer","Summer","Autumn","Autumn","Autumn","Winter")
```

The formula for the Southern Hemisphere in C2 is

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH(A2),"Summer","Summer","Autumn","Autumn","Autumn","Winter","Winter","Winter","Spring","Spring","Spring","Summer")
```

If you want the seasons to begin at the solstice and equinox dates, then use this for Northern hemisphere:

```
=IF(DAY(A2)<22,CHOOSE(MONTH(A2),"Winter","Winter","Winter","Spring","Spring","Spring","Summer","Summer","Summer","Autumn","Autumn","Autumn","Winter"),CHOOSE(MONTH(A2),"Winter","Winter","Spring","Spring","Spring","Summer","Summer","Summer","Autumn","Autumn","Autumn","Winter"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasn't paying attention to different hemispheres!

Answer (score 3):

There are two definitions of seasons; the Astronomical Seasons (AS), and the Meteorological Seasons (MS). the AS depend on equinoxes and solstices. I.e. they start on 21st of months. while the MS are easier for weather forecasting and so, and they start in the 1st of months.
The seasons also depend on the location (northern or southern the hemisphere.
Here are the dates and corresponding seasons depending on the location and method:

```
     Season at 
(Northern/Southern) 
    Hemisphere                Astronomical             Meteorological
Winter / Summer              21/12 to 20/03            01/12 to end/02
Spring / Fall*               21/03 to 20/06            01/03 to  30/05
Summer / Winter              21/06 to 20/09            01/06 to  31/08             
Fall*  / Spring              21/09 to 20/12            01/09 to  31/01
```

In Excel we can get the Day of Year (DOY) by the following formula:
If you store the date in cell G5 for example, then DOY =

```
=G5-DATE(YEAR(G5),1,1)
```

For (AS): The corresponding DOY of 21/03, 21/06, and 21/09 are 80, 172, 264

For (MS): The corresponding DOY of 01/03, 01/06, and 01/09 are 60, 152, 244

Although the Choose formulas above are awesome, but I would write it in simple if conditions to be easily transformed to any programming language.

**Example:**
The *Astronomical season* of the *Northern hemisphere* is calculated as follows:

```
=if((DOY<80,"Winter",iF(DOY<172,"Spring",iF(DOY<264,"Summer","Fall")))
```

To calculate the season for southern hemisphere or for the meteorological method, one can use the above table to modify the equation easily.

---

- *Fall* is called *Autumn* in some parts of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Month name is in A1, and Winter begins in January, use:

```
=IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1 & " 1"))<4,"Winter",IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1 & " 1"))<7,"Spring",IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1 & " 1"))<10,"Summer","Autumn")))
```

Comment: where does Winter ***begin*** in January?

Comment: The OP mentioned that they want the season per month. Winter starts December 21, which is closer to January than December.

Answer (score 0):

shorter version:   =LOOKUP(MONTH(TODAY()),{1,2,5,8,11;"Winter","Spring","Summer","Fall","Winter"})